# Upload file to .net 6 api in react native

Tags: android, react-native, api, .net-core

I tried lot of ways to send media to my api. The only one working solution is base64 string but its  ideal for videos.  Please show me the light

I tried to send Blob in Formdata,File is not possible, metadata (uri, name, type) - i wanted to read from stream but realized that won't work, lastly bytes but it refused as well. On the api i tried IFormFile, FormCollection, httprequest and custom request with blob and other params. It was refused. In header i wrote multi, and for bytes something different. Totally hopeless at the moment. All the tutorials and helps write {name, type, uri} but its refused in the formdata since it can only be string and Blob.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.